# Enable use of images from the local library on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, serverless, minikube, openfaas

I'm following a tutorial https://docs.openfaas.com/tutorials/first-python-function/,

currently, I have the right image

```sh
$ docker images | grep hello-openfaas
wm/hello-openfaas                                     latest                          bd08d01ce09b   34 minutes ago      65.2MB
$ faas-cli deploy -f ./hello-openfaas.yml 
Deploying: hello-openfaas.
WARNING! You are not using an encrypted connection to the gateway, consider using HTTPS.

Deployed. 202 Accepted.
URL: http://IP:8099/function/hello-openfaas
```

there is a step that forewarns me to do some setup(My case is I'm using `Kubernetes` and `minikube` and don't want to push to a remote container registry, I should enable the use of images from the local library on Kubernetes.), I see the hints

```
see the helm chart for how to set the ImagePullPolicy
```

I'm not sure how to configure it correctly. the final result indicates I failed.

Unsurprisingly, I couldn't access the function service, I find some clues in  https://docs.openfaas.com/deployment/troubleshooting/#openfaas-didnt-start which might help to diagnose the problem.

```
$ kubectl logs -n openfaas-fn deploy/hello-openfaas
Error from server (BadRequest): container "hello-openfaas" in pod "hello-openfaas-558f99477f-wd697" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image

$ kubectl describe -n openfaas-fn deploy/hello-openfaas
Name:                   hello-openfaas
Namespace:              openfaas-fn
CreationTimestamp:      Wed, 16 Mar 2022 14:59:49 +0800
Labels:                 faas_function=hello-openfaas
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                        prometheus.io.scrape: false
Selector:               faas_function=hello-openfaas
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  0 max unavailable, 1 max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:       faas_function=hello-openfaas
  Annotations:  prometheus.io.scrape: false
  Containers:
   hello-openfaas:
    Image:      wm/hello-openfaas:latest
    Port:       8080/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Liveness:   http-get http://:8080/_/health delay=2s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:8080/_/health delay=2s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      fprocess:  python3 index.py
    Mounts:      <none>
  Volumes:       <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing    False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   hello-openfaas-558f99477f (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  29m   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set hello-openfaas-558f99477f to 1
```

`hello-openfaas.yml`

```yaml
version: 1.0
provider:
  name: openfaas
  gateway: http://IP:8099
functions:
  hello-openfaas:
    lang: python3
    handler: ./hello-openfaas
    image: wm/hello-openfaas:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Never
```

---

I create a new project `hello-openfaas2` to reproduce this error

```sh
$ faas-cli new --lang python3 hello-openfaas2 --prefix="wm"
Folder: hello-openfaas2 created.
# I add `imagePullPolicy: Never` to `hello-openfaas2.yml`
$ faas-cli build -f ./hello-openfaas2.yml 
$ faas-cli deploy -f ./hello-openfaas2.yml 
Deploying: hello-openfaas2.
WARNING! You are not using an encrypted connection to the gateway, consider using HTTPS.

Deployed. 202 Accepted.
URL: http://192.168.1.3:8099/function/hello-openfaas2


$ kubectl logs -n openfaas-fn deploy/hello-openfaas2
Error from server (BadRequest): container "hello-openfaas2" in pod "hello-openfaas2-7c67488865-7d7vm" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled

$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
kube-system            coredns-64897985d-kp7vf                     1/1     Running            0                47h
...
openfaas-fn            env-6c79f7b946-bzbtm                        1/1     Running            0                4h28m
openfaas-fn            figlet-54db496f88-957xl                     1/1     Running            0                18h
openfaas-fn            hello-openfaas-547857b9d6-z277c             0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0                127m
openfaas-fn            hello-openfaas-7b6946b4f9-hcvq4             0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0                165m
openfaas-fn            hello-openfaas2-7c67488865-qmrkl            0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0                13m
openfaas-fn            hello-openfaas3-65847b8b67-b94kd            0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0                97m
openfaas-fn            hello-python-554b464498-zxcdv               0/1     ErrImagePull       0                3h23m
openfaas-fn            hello-python-8698bc68bd-62gh9               0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0                3h25m
```

---

from https://docs.openfaas.com/reference/yaml/, I know I put the `imagePullPolicy` in the wrong place, there is no such keyword in its schema.

I also tried `eval $(minikube docker-env` and still get the same error.

---

I've a feeling that `faas-cli deploy` can be replace by `helm`, they all mean to run the image(whether from remote or local) in Kubernetes cluster, then I can use `helm chart` to setup the `pullPolicy` there. Even though the detail is not still clear to me, This discovery inspires me.

---

So far, after `eval $(minikube docker-env)`

```sh
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
wm/hello-openfaas2                        0.1        03c21bd96d5e   About an hour ago   65.2MB
python                                    3-alpine   69fba17b9bae   12 days ago         48.6MB
ghcr.io/openfaas/figlet                   latest     ca5eef0de441   2 weeks ago         14.8MB
ghcr.io/openfaas/alpine                   latest     35f3d4be6bb8   2 weeks ago         14.2MB
ghcr.io/openfaas/faas-netes               0.14.2     524b510505ec   3 weeks ago         77.3MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver                 v1.23.3    f40be0088a83   7 weeks ago         135MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager        v1.23.3    b07520cd7ab7   7 weeks ago         125MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler                 v1.23.3    99a3486be4f2   7 weeks ago         53.5MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy                     v1.23.3    9b7cc9982109   7 weeks ago         112MB
ghcr.io/openfaas/gateway                  0.21.3     ab4851262cd1   7 weeks ago         30.6MB
ghcr.io/openfaas/basic-auth               0.21.3     16e7168a17a3   7 weeks ago         14.3MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd                           3.5.1-0    25f8c7f3da61   4 months ago        293MB
ghcr.io/openfaas/classic-watchdog         0.2.0      6f97aa96da81   4 months ago        8.18MB
k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns                v1.8.6     a4ca41631cc7   5 months ago        46.8MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause                          3.6        6270bb605e12   6 months ago        683kB
ghcr.io/openfaas/queue-worker             0.12.2     56e7216201bc   7 months ago        7.97MB
kubernetesui/dashboard                    v2.3.1     e1482a24335a   9 months ago        220MB
kubernetesui/metrics-scraper              v1.0.7     7801cfc6d5c0   9 months ago        34.4MB
nats-streaming                            0.22.0     12f2d32e0c9a   9 months ago        19.8MB
gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner   v5         6e38f40d628d   11 months ago       31.5MB
functions/markdown-render                 latest     93b5da182216   2 years ago         24.6MB
functions/hubstats                        latest     01affa91e9e4   2 years ago         29.3MB
functions/nodeinfo                        latest     2fe8a87bf79c   2 years ago         71.4MB
functions/alpine                          latest     46c6f6d74471   2 years ago         21.5MB
prom/prometheus                           v2.11.0    b97ed892eb23   2 years ago         126MB
prom/alertmanager                         v0.18.0    ce3c87f17369   2 years ago         51.9MB
alexellis2/openfaas-colorization          0.4.1      d36b67b1b5c1   2 years ago         1.84GB
rorpage/text-to-speech                    latest     5dc20810eb54   2 years ago         86.9MB
stefanprodan/faas-grafana                 4.6.3      2a4bd9caea50   4 years ago         284MB

$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
kube-system            coredns-64897985d-kp7vf                     1/1     Running            0               6d
kube-system            etcd-minikube                               1/1     Running            0               6d
kube-system            kube-apiserver-minikube                     1/1     Running            0               6d
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-minikube            1/1     Running            0               6d
kube-system            kube-proxy-5m8lr                            1/1     Running            0               6d
kube-system            kube-scheduler-minikube                     1/1     Running            0               6d
kube-system            storage-provisioner                         1/1     Running            1 (6d ago)      6d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-58549894f-97tsv   1/1     Running            0               5d7h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-ccd587f44-lkwcx        1/1     Running            0               5d7h
openfaas-fn            base64-6bdbcdb64c-djz8f                     1/1     Running            0               5d1h
openfaas-fn            colorise-85c74c686b-2fz66                   1/1     Running            0               4d5h
openfaas-fn            echoit-5d7df6684c-k6ljn                     1/1     Running            0               5d1h
openfaas-fn            env-6c79f7b946-bzbtm                        1/1     Running            0               4d5h
openfaas-fn            figlet-54db496f88-957xl                     1/1     Running            0               4d19h
openfaas-fn            hello-openfaas-547857b9d6-z277c             0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0               4d3h
openfaas-fn            hello-openfaas-7b6946b4f9-hcvq4             0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0               4d3h
openfaas-fn            hello-openfaas2-5c6f6cb5d9-24hkz            0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0               9m22s
openfaas-fn            hello-openfaas2-8957bb47b-7cgjg             0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0               2d22h
openfaas-fn            hello-openfaas3-65847b8b67-b94kd            0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0               4d2h
openfaas-fn            hello-python-6d6976845f-cwsln               0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0               3d19h
openfaas-fn            hello-python-b577cb8dc-64wf5                0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0               3d9h
openfaas-fn            hubstats-b6cd4dccc-z8tvl                    1/1     Running            0               5d1h
openfaas-fn            markdown-68f69f47c8-w5m47                   1/1     Running            0               5d1h
openfaas-fn            nodeinfo-d48cbbfcc-hfj79                    1/1     Running            0               5d1h
openfaas-fn            openfaas2-fun                               1/1     Running            0               15s
openfaas-fn            text-to-speech-74ffcdfd7-997t4              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2235 (3s ago)   4d5h
openfaas-fn            wordcount-6489865566-cvfzr                  1/1     Running            0               5d1h
openfaas               alertmanager-88449c789-fq2rg                1/1     Running            0               3d1h
openfaas               basic-auth-plugin-75fd7d69c5-zw4jh          1/1     Running            0               3d2h
openfaas               gateway-5c4bb7c5d7-n8h27                    2/2     Running            0               3d2h
openfaas               grafana                                     1/1     Running            0               4d8h
openfaas               nats-647b476664-hkr7p                       1/1     Running            0               3d2h
openfaas               prometheus-687648749f-tl8jp                 1/1     Running            0               3d1h
openfaas               queue-worker-7777ffd7f6-htx6t               1/1     Running            0               3d2h


$ kubectl get -o yaml -n openfaas-fn deploy/hello-openfaas2
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "6"
    prometheus.io.scrape: "false"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-03-17T12:47:35Z"
  generation: 6
  labels:
    faas_function: hello-openfaas2
  name: hello-openfaas2
  namespace: openfaas-fn
  resourceVersion: "400833"
  uid: 9c4e9d26-23af-4f93-8538-4e2d96f0d7e0
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      faas_function: hello-openfaas2
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io.scrape: "false"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        faas_function: hello-openfaas2
        uid: "969512830"
      name: hello-openfaas2
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: fprocess
          value: python3 index.py
        image: wm/hello-openfaas2:0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /_/health
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 2
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: hello-openfaas2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /_/health
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 2
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      enableServiceLinks: false
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-03-17T12:47:35Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-03-17T12:47:35Z"
    message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
    status: "False"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-03-20T12:16:56Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-03-20T12:16:56Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "hello-openfaas2-5d6c7c7fb4" has timed out progressing.
    reason: ProgressDeadlineExceeded
    status: "False"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 6
  replicas: 2
  unavailableReplicas: 2
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

---

In one shell,

```sh
docker@minikube:~$ docker run  --name wm -ti wm/hello-openfaas2:0.1
2022/03/20 13:04:52 Version: 0.2.0  SHA: 56bf6aac54deb3863a690f5fc03a2a38e7d9e6ef
2022/03/20 13:04:52 Timeouts: read: 5s write: 5s hard: 0s health: 5s.
2022/03/20 13:04:52 Listening on port: 8080
...
```

and another shell

```
docker@minikube:~$ docker ps | grep wm
d7796286641c   wm/hello-openfaas2:0.1             "fwatchdog"              3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)   8080/tcp   wm
```

Comment: After `eval $(minikube docker-env)`, when you run `docker images|grep <img>`, do you have the same result showing on top of your post? Iis there any chance your Minikube img cache doesn't match that of your workstation (typically using KVM, vbox, ... most drivers setting up Minikube: the container runtime of your cluster is distinct from that of your host, AFAIR). Check that when deploying openfaas, your values file has a `faasnetes.imagePullPolicy=Never` or IfNotPresent. I don't think you can put an imagePullPolicy in your hello-openfaas.yml / check kubectl get  deploy/hello-openfaas -o yaml

Comment: @SYN "do you have the same result showing on top of your post?", no, they are pretty different.  "is there any chance your Minikube img cache doesn't match that of your workstation", yes

Comment: @SYN I tried `kubectl get deploy/hello-openfaas2 -o yaml`, the output is
`Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "hello-openfaas2" not found`

Comment: sorry, not enought characters allowed in a single comment: obviously, should be kubectl get *-n openpaas-fn*. Nevermind, posted an answer: your previous comment was just what I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify an image to pull from without a url, this defaults to [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/). When you use `:latest` tag, it will always pull the latest image regardless of what pull policy is defined.

So to use local built images - *don't use the latest tag.*

To make minikube pull images from your local machine, you need to do few things:

1. Point your docker client to the VM's docker daemon: `eval $(minikube docker-env)`
2. Configure image pull policy: `imagePullPolicy: Never`
3. There is a flag to pass in to use insecure registries in minikube VM. This must be specified when you create the machine: `minikube start --insecure-registry`

Note you have to run eval `eval $(minikube docker-env)` on each terminal you want to use, since it only sets the environment variables for the current shell session.

This flow works:

```sh
# Start minikube and set docker env
minikube start
eval $(minikube docker-env)

# Build image
docker build -t foo:1.0 .

# Run in minikube
kubectl run hello-foo --image=foo:1.0 --image-pull-policy=Never
```

You can read more at the [minikube docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/0c616a6b42b28a1aab8397f5a9061f8ebbd9f3d9/README.md#reusing-the-docker-daemon).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help, seems I'd better use `faas-cli deploy` to run this image, as there exist dependencies https://docs.openfaas.com/images/of-conceptual-operator.png

Answer (score 2):

If your image has a `latest` tag, the Pod's `ImagePullPolicy` will be automatically set to `Always`. Each time the pod is created, Kubernetes tries to pull the newest image.

Try not tagging the image as `latest` or manually setting the Pod's `ImagePullPolicy` to `Never`.
If you're using static manifest to create a Pod, the setting will be like the following:

```
containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: testImage:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Comment: I'm a beginner to Kubernetes, approach to manually set the Pod's `ImagePullPolicy` to `Never` is tricky to me. I checked `helm` suggested by the author,  didn't figure out how so far.

Comment: I've added a sample description in my answer. I've never used Helm but this may help: helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/pods/#imagepullpolicy

Answer (score 1):

From comments in initial post, I gathered that:

- The issue is that the container runtime from your Minikube cluster is distinct from that of your host, where you have built your function image (not always the case: minikube can run [with docker driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/#linux), which, *I think* implies the host docker runtime is shared with cluster)
- the container runtime in use by Minikube is docker (could have been cri-o / following steps won't apply to that case. Those using crio may [switch to docker](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/#runtime-configuration), as [I'm not sure image loading is possible with cri-o](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/issues/707) )

You can try to build your function image from a shell inside your Minikube instance.

Or you can:

- export your image ( `docker save -o image.tar my/image` )
- copy this to your minikube instance ( `scp -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa image.tar docker@$(minikube ip):` )
- open a shell ( `ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip)` )
- load that image ( `docker load -i image.tar` )

Then, make sure your openfaas was deployed with `faasnetes.imagePullPolicy=Never` or `IfNotPresent`, as I doubt setting the imagePullPolicy directly in your function would do (haven't read about this in their docs, which instead mentions, as you pointed it out, to override this during openfaas deployment). Checking your deployment yaml definition ( `kubectl get -o yaml -n openpaas-fn deploy/hello-openfaas` ) should confirm you're not using `Always`: if that's already the case, no need to dig further: just make sure your image is imported, with name and tag matching that referenced by your function.

---

... Answering your last comment: you're not sure how openfaas was deployed. One way to make sure the proper option was set would be to look at the gateway deployment, in openfaas namespace ( `kubectl get -o yaml -n openfaas deploy/gateway` ).

In there, you should find a container named "operator". That container should include a few environment variables, one of which may be `image_pull_policy`. (we can see this looking at [the Chart sources](https://github.com/openfaas/faas-netes/blob/master/chart/openfaas/templates/gateway-dep.yaml#L194-L195) ). You want that environment variable to be set to `IfNotPresent`, add it or edit it if needed.

Checking your last edit, we can see the Deployment object created by your function says:

```
    image: wm/hello-openfaas2:0.1
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

So for sure: you do need to reconfigure openfaas, adding that `image_pull_policy` environment variable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to ensure `openfaas`was deployed with `faasnetes.imagePullPolicy=Never`, I added the output of `kubectl get -o yaml -n openfaas-fn deploy/hello-openfaas2` in the post.

Comment: Thanks: that yaml confirms that, in addition to importing your image in the proper container runtime, you will have to reconfigure openfaas (edited my answer). Let me know if you need further clarifications

Comment: I executed`kubectl get -o yaml -n openfaas deploy/gateway > wm.yaml` and edited it, modified `image_pull_policy` from `Always` to `IfNotPresent`, what should I do with this YAML file.

Comment: you can `kubectl edit -n openfaas deploy/gateway` to update it directly in cluster. Otherwise, having dumped it to a file, fixed it: you can just `kubectl apply -f <your-file>`. gateway pod should restart, .. then you're good to go.

Comment: I'm already at the step `docker load -i wm.tar`, which says `Loaded image: wm/hello-openfaas2:0.1`. then I run `kubectl apply -f wm.yaml`, it says `Warning: resource deployments/gateway is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
deployment.apps/gateway configured`

Comment: Obviously, I have already gotten enough suggestions, even though I didn't achieve the final goal, which is to access the service provided by the function image, the answer to the initial question is much clear to me now, Further problems would and should be posted in a new question.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the "Warning: resource deployments/gateway ...", this log is to be expected, when the resource was created with `kubectl create`, and you're running `kubectl apply` updating that resource. Next `kubectl apply` shouldn't complain. Another way to do this would have been to `kubectl replace` the object, avoiding the error. Also: try re-creating your functions, maybe the existing hello deployments weren't updated after reconfiguring your gateway.